# Manipulating Mono and Flux transformation

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using Spring 5 webflux with ReactiveMongoRepositories.
Suppose I have 2 collections "Race" and "RaceParticipation":

```
    Race : {
    "_id" : "ID",
    "name" : "Name"
    }

    RaceParticipation : {
    "_id" : "ID",
    "userId" : "ID",
    "raceId" : "ID"
    }
```

I need to find a page of Races in which a given user has participated.

The solution I went with is call `raceParticipationRepository.findByUserId("userId", PageRequest.of(0,10))`
This returns a `Flux<UserParticipation>`.
The I should collect the ids from the response and call `raceRepository.findAllById(ids)`.

Here is a snippet:

```
Flux<Race> findUserRaces(String userId, int page){
    return raceParticipationRepository.findByUserId(userId, status,
                PageRequest.of(page, 6))
            .collectList()
            .map(list -> list.stream()
                    .map(ParticipationRepository::getRaceId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .flatMap(list -> raceRepository.findAllById(list));
}
```

This code doesn't compile. `"Required Flux<Race> but flatMap was inferred to Mono..."`

Any idea on what I'm missing or how should I do?

Comment: If you can, please don't code something in Java that you can do in SQL - its less performant by a huge factor, although it's more entertaining to write java.

Comment: It's a MongoDB database with no DBRef. How would u do that without Java?

Comment: Ah, overread the "Mongo" part, sorry for that; I also posted an answer, since I guessed that you need the Java part anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `collectList()` part, since it makes a Mono from your Flux, which you obviously don't want - you're making a stream from the list immediately after collection.  This here should do the same, plus mapping the Mono to a Flux with flatMapMany:

```
raceParticipationRepository.findByUserId(userId, status,
            PageRequest.of(page, 6))
      .map(ParticipationRepository::getRaceId)
                .collectList(Collectors.toList()) // returns Mono<List>
      .flatMapMany(list -> raceRepository.findAllById(list)); // Mono -> Flux again
```

Comment: I'm using collectList before ParticipationRepository::getRaceId because I don't want to make a database for each raceParticipation object. I want to collect the results of the 1st call then make 1 call with the list of Ids to get all the races in 1 shot

Comment: Yes, I gathered, but I think you're doing the collectList one time to much, since you can do the mapping to getRacId in the flux, and then collectList.
you then have a Mono<List>, that you can put in a flatMapMany, and get a Flux of the data back.